# Is it better to edit or to flag, when a simple rephrase of a question would make it on topic?

Tags: discussion, flags, etiquette, moderation

Eg.: a user asks for "the best solution" to a problem, but from the context you can infer that he/she just needs a solution, a working example.

Similarly, the user asks for a "tutorial" (external example) when an example could be given on SO, is quite probably everything the OP needs, and would answer the question.

Should the preferred approach be "Flagging" for non conformity, or editing the question in order to salvage it when possible?

Comment: If you believe that the question is salvageable you should edit it rather than flagging it. Be careful not to change the meaning of the question though. Also, since you are under 2K rep, your edit needs to be approved by reviewers, so write a good edit summary before submitting the edit.

Comment: Just please, please, please fix everything that you can see in the post. **Do not** just turn "best solution" into "solution" while leaving spelling and grammar errors for someone else to fix.

Comment: @TinyGiant - I wish I could "+2" to your remark... In any case, it's a good question

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit!

Edit edit edit edit!

Flags should only be used for issues that you don't have the powers to deal with yourself. Everybody can edit. There is no need to flag over issues you can trivially fix.

<sub>As a relevant aside, if a trivial rephrasing that doesn't change what the question is asking makes it clearly on-topic, then it's *already on topic* and nobody should be voting to close it. I get really annoyed when people vote to close *"what do you reckon is the best way to foo the bar?"* as "primarily opinion based" or *"is there some tool I can use to foo the bar?"* as a tool recommendation question even when *"How can I foo the bar?"* would be clearly on-topic and the other two are just that same question with slightly different language. But people *do* regularly close such questions, whether I like it or not, so editing them in ways that preserve their meaning but remove the arbitrary patterns of speech that the Nazi close voters object to is a sensible pragmatic measure to stop them from being closed.</sub>

Comment: Agreed, but it has the downside that it doesn't scale. We seem to have many more badly written questions than editors :/

Comment: "Badly written" isn't the same as "needs a simple rephrase to conform to the letter of the rules", though, @David. I'm addressing only the latter, here. For badly written questions, it might be reasonable to vote/flag to close as "unclear what you're asking" (although I'd suggest trying to make sure that you spot understandable, non-duplicate questions of potential value to future visitors that are merely badly written and edit those ones instead of trying to have them closed).

Comment: I meant "badly written'' as in not following what is recommended in help. And I'm well aware of how to vote/flag/salvage questions - I spend a lot of time on SU doing exactly that.

Comment: Addressing your aside, there is a case for which I vtc without editing: Editing would make the question off-topic, but differently. For example, _"is there a tool to foo the bar?"_ is a tool rec, but _"how to foo the bar?"_ would be too broad for these specific _foo_ and _bar_.

Comment: @MarkAmery You totally convinced me with this answer. However to argue a bit against editing, I recently found myself in the situation that I had to abort an edit (aimed at making a question ontopic) because I discovered during the edit that indeed it's not clear what the OP wanted (foo the bar, bar the foo, foobar the barfoo?). And that even when at first glance it looked like a simple, editable case. So one has to still be careful.

Comment: The fact that the OP asks this question is anecdotical evidence that everything is not as clear cut as you think. I therefore object to you classifying any group of close voters under the category *Nazi close voters*. Everybody has to and should be allowed to learn and your *arbitrary patterns of speech* may not be somebody else's. Still an upvote for the concise answer though.

Answer (score 13):

**Edit!**

If you click **flag**, then maybe you could see something like:

> This question is completely unclear, incomplete, overly-broad, primarily opinion-based or is not about programming as described in the help center, and it is **unlikely to be fixed via editing.**

So if edit can fix the post's problem, just edit it. If really can't fix the problem via editing, then flag/vote to close it.

---

**But!** If a question was asking for *a working example*, but OP didn't try anything. Then the question maybe is a **too broad** question:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.